# 15 second Comment Timeout should Apply Per Post

Tags: feature-request, comments

I wrote a comment to an answer.

I then wrote a comment to the question.

I then waited 15 seconds (I thought).

And I had to wait another 15 seconds (I counted).

But I counted too fast, so I came here to complain instead.

---

I can see that it makes sense to prevent a flood of comments to a particular question or answer, but I don't see what's served by preventing me from quickly entering one comment for the question, and one for each answer.

---

And, besides that, if you're going to make me wait 15 seconds, then you should display a countdown! You have the technology; you can do it.

Comment: It shouldn't apply even on a per post basis. Resetting that f-ing timer every f-ing time you post too early is an act of pointless cruelty. (And +1 for a countdown.)

Comment: Yet the 5 second upvote comment timer doesn't reset.